# How to extract .zip through ADB shell

Tags: adb

Exactly what the title says.  I've got a 1.5 gb zip file on my sdcard that I would like to extract via adb (not pulling to pc and pushing back).  Is there a simple command to unzip a file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes and no. As far as I'm aware, a typical Android install will not contain `unzip`. You can, however, install busybox for Android, which provides the `unzip` utility. Then a simple:

```
adb shell unzip /sdcard/archive.zip
```

Would do the trick. If you're rooted you can use a busybox installer from the Market [like Stericson's](https://market.android.com/details?id=stericson.busybox&hl=en). If you're *not* rooted then you should be able to manually push a busybox binary ([one here on Github](https://github.com/Gnurou/busybox-android/blob/master/busybox-android), for example; click "raw" to download it) to somewhere like `/data/local` and then invoke it. It should be something like:

```
adb push /path/to/busybox-android /data/local/busybox
adb shell chmod 0755 /data/local/busybox #Make it executable
adb shell /data/local/busybox unzip /sdcard/archive.zip
```

Alternatively, many file managers will unzip files for you. I personally use [File Expert](https://market.android.com/details?id=xcxin.filexpert&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsInhjeGluLmZpbGV4cGVydCJd) but there are a lot of others. Usually you just need to long press on the archive and it will present an "extract" option or similar.

Comment: Awesome answer. busybox is a powerful tool.

Comment: I had to change directory first: adb shell; cd /sdcard; /data/local/busybox unzip archive.zip

Comment: The `shell` user doesn't have permissions for `/data/local` on my phone — a Galaxy S4 running Android 5. I had to `push` `busybox` to `/data/local/tmp`.  Not sure yet if that directory's contents persist across reboots.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use /data/local/tmp as well and able to chmod also. I was not able to do was unzip the zip file I created in windows.

To overcome this, i created the tar file using 7zip and used busybox tar -xvf myzip.tar destination to successfully unzip the file.