# How do I create an archive for easy extraction to /data/local/tmp/ in "adb shell"?

Tags: adb, shell, command-line, file-archives

Usual [shar archives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shar) fail to extact in `adb shell` due to problems with lock directory and temporary files for HERE documents. Zip archives [are also not an option](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/18711/how-to-extract-zip-through-adb-shell).

How do I make an archive that can be easily extracted to `/data/local/tmp/` out of the box on unrooted Android without busybox?

Answer (score 1):

You can install `busybox` pretty easily on an unrooted Android phone.  Steps:

- Grab the file [`busybox-android`](https://github.com/Gnurou/busybox-android/raw/master/busybox-android) from [the eponymous github project](https://github.com/Gnurou/busybox-android).
- Get it onto your device via `scp`, `adb push`, Android File Transfer, etc.  Put it somewhere public that you'll have access to from a Terminal Emulator session.  Just call it `busybox`.
- Start a Terminal Emulator session.  Make a directory `~/bin` and copy the `busybox` file from the public place you put it to that new directory.

  - Since the `cp` command is not available in a Terminal Emulator session (!) do it this way: `cat $PATH_TO_BUSYBOX/busybox > ~/bin/busybox`
- Now `cd ~/bin` and create a symbolic link: `ln -s busybox tar`.

So now create a tarball using `tar czv $FILENAME $ROOT_OF_FILES_TO_ARCHIVE`, kick it over to your device, and extract using `tar xzv $FILENAME`.

`tar` is also available by default to `ssh` sessions served by [SSHDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=berserker.android.apps.sshdroid) (because SSHDroid provides `busybox`).  You might need to register it?  Don't remember if that stuff works on the free version.

Comment: Is there a tool to create self-extracting archives for Android, to be able to unwrap complex structure (e.g. Valgrind) in `/data/local/tmp/` in one move, without preparation step?

Comment: If there is, it would likely use the POSIX toolkit provided by `busybox`.

Comment: It can be shellscript+busybox+datafile bundled in one file.

Comment: Hmm. How would you extract the busybox from the bundle without the POSIX toolkit?

Comment: The bundle can start with `#!/system/bin/sh`, which will somehow extract busybox from it, then call `busybox tar -xf`.

Comment: Well, yes.  But the "somehow" is really the crux of the issue.  I did just notice that `dd` is available, so that would be one way.  Maybe you should ask another question to see if somebody has found such a program or is writing one.

Comment: There's also an [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=burrows.apps.busybox&hl=en) that installs busybox on an unrooted phone.  Though I guess by "out of the box" you mean "with no applications installed".